# Reshape Pandas dataframe by specific string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv dataset that looks like this:

```
###12345
LABEL     text
LABEL     text
###12213
LABEL     text
LABEL     text
```

I want to transform it to that shape

```
12345 LABEL    text
12345 LABEL    text
12213 LABEL    text
```

My first approach was to filter out the lines like this

```
#df['label'].str.contains("###", na=False)
```

but had no success in rearranging as an index.

Could you help me on this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
print (df)
            label
0        ###12345
1  LABEL     text
2  LABEL     text
3        ###12213
4  LABEL     text
5  LABEL     text
```

---

```
#boolean mask
m = df['label'].str.contains("###", na=False) 
#helper column with repalce non ### values to NaNs and repalce it by last non NaN value
df['new'] = df['label'].where(m).ffill()
#remove rows with same values
df = df[df['label'] != df['new']].copy()
#extract new column and add to original
df['label'] = df.pop('new').str.lstrip('#') + ' ' + df['label']
print (df)
                  label
1  12345 LABEL     text
2  12345 LABEL     text
4  12213 LABEL     text
5  12213 LABEL     text
```

---

```
print (df)
      label value
0  ###12345   NaN
1     LABEL  text
2     LABEL  text
3  ###12213   NaN
4     LABEL  text
5     LABEL  text


m = df['label'].str.contains("###", na=False) 

df['new'] = df['label'].where(m).ffill()
df = df[df['label'] != df['new']].copy()
df['label'] = df.pop('new').str.lstrip('#') + ' ' + df['label']
print (df)
         label value
1  12345 LABEL  text
2  12345 LABEL  text
4  12213 LABEL  text
5  12213 LABEL  text
```